# Thread-local Python Print

Tags: python, python-multithreading

Are there any built-in ways to have different threads have different destinations for `print()` and similar?

I'm exploring the creation of an interactive Python environment, so I can't just use `print()` from module spamegg. It has to be the globally available one with no arguments.

Comment: What do you mean "the globally available one with no arguments"? The globally available `print` function takes 0 or more arguments. You can just as easily define another `print` function that does the same. (Unless you're using Python 2.x and not using `from __future__ import print_function`, in which case `print` isn't a function in the first place, it's a special kind of statement, and you can't replace it at all.)

Comment: Meanwhile, if you want different destinations, you can do that by replacing `sys.stdout`, but that's a global on `sys`, so that doesn't help. You're pretty much going to have to create some namespace (presumably a module, but it could be a fake builtins or an `exec` context or who knows what without knowing more about your design…) that has a `print` function in it.

Comment: @abarnert Without using `print(..., file=spamegg)`

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `sys.stdout` with an object that checks the current thread and writes to the appropriate file:

```
import sys, threading

class CustomOutput(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # the "softspace" slot is used internally by Python's print
        # to keep track of whether to prepend space to the
        # printed expression
        self.softspace = 0
        self._old_stdout = None

    def activate(self):
        self._old_stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = self

    def deactivate(self):
        sys.stdout = self._old_stdout
        self._old_stdout = None

    def write(self, s):
        # actually write to an open file obtained from an attribute
        # on the current thread
        threading.current_thread().open_file.write(s)

    def writelines(self, seq):
        for s in seq:
            self.write(s)

    def close(self):
        pass

    def flush(self):
        pass

    def isatty(self):
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

It *is* possible to do what you're asking, although it's complicated and clunky and possibly not portable, and I don't think it's what you want to do.

Your objection to just using `spamegg.print` is:

> I'm exploring the creation of an interactive Python environment, so I can't just use `print()` from module `spamegg`. It has to be the globally available one with no arguments.

But the solution to that is easy: Just use `print` from module `spamegg` in your code, and `from spamegg import print` in the interactive interpreter. That's all there is to it.

For that matter, there's no good reason this even needs to be called `print` in the first place. If all of your code used some other output function with a different name, you could do the same thing in the interactive interpreter.

---

But how does that let each thread have a different destination?

The easy way to do that is to just look up the destination in a [`threading.local()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-local-data).

---

But if you really want to do both parts of this the hard way, you can.

To do the global `print` the hard way, you can either have `spamegg` replace the builtin `print` instead of just giving you a way to shadow it, or have it replace `sys.stdout`, so the builtin `print` with default arguments will print somewhere else.

```
import builtins
_real_print = builtins.print
def _print(*args, **kwargs):
    kwargs.setdefault('file', my_output_destination)
    _real_print(*args, **kwargs)
builtins.print = _print

import io
import sys
class MyStdOut(io.TextIOBase):
    # ... __init__, write, etc.
sys.stdout = MyStdOut()
```

That still requires having `MyStdOut` use a thread-local target.

Alternatively, you can compile or wrap each thread function in its own custom `globals` environment that replaces `__builtins__` and/or `sys` from the default, allowing you to give a different one to each thread from the start. For example:

```
from functools import partial
from threading import Thread
from types import FunctionType

class MyThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if target:
            g = target.__globals__.copy()
            g['__builtins__'] = g['__builtins__'].copy()
            output = make_output_for_new_thread()
            g['__builtins__']['print'] = partial(print, file=output)
            target = FunctionType(thread_func.__code__, g, thread_func.__name__, 
                                  thread_func.__defaults__, thread_func.__closure__)
        super().__init__(self, group, target, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score -1):

I might have solution for you, but it's quite more complicated than just print.

```
class ClusteredLogging(object):
    '''
    Class gathers all logs performed inside with statement and flush
    it to mainHandler on exit at once.
    Good for multithreaded applications that has to log several
    lines at once.
    '''


    def __init__(self, mainHandler, formatter):
        self.mainHandler = mainHandler
        self.formatter = formatter

        self.buffer = StringIO()
        self.handler = logging.StreamHandler(self.buffer)
        self.handler.setFormatter(formatter)


    def __enter__(self):
        rootLogger = logging.getLogger()
        rootLogger.addHandler(self.handler)


    def __exit__(self, t, value, tb):
        rootLogger = logging.getLogger()
        rootLogger.removeHandler(self.handler)
        self.handler.flush()
        self.buffer.flush()

        rootLogger.addHandler(self.mainHandler)
        logging.info(self.buffer.getvalue().strip())
        rootLogger.removeHandler(self.mainHandler)
```

Using this, you can create log handler for each thread and configure them to store logs to different locations.

Keep in mind that this is developed with slightly different goal in mind (see comments) but you can adapt it by taking handler juggling feature of ClusteredLogging as a start.

And some test code:

```
import concurrent.futures
try:
    from StringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO
import logging
import sys

# put ClusteredLogging here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)8s\t%(message)s')
    onlyMessageFormatter = logging.Formatter("%(message)s")
    mainHandler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    mainHandler.setFormatter(onlyMessageFormatter)
    mainHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    rootLogger = logging.getLogger()
    rootLogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    def logSomethingLong(label):
        with ClusteredLogging(mainHandler, formatter):
            for i in range(15):
                logging.info(label + " " + str(i))        

    labels = ("TEST", "EXPERIMENT", "TRIAL")

    executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()
    futures = [executor.submit(logSomethingLong, label) for label in labels]
    concurrent.futures.wait(futures)
```

Comment: I'd appreciate any comment why it's not useful.